# Elastic search cluster.name property

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a file named "elasticsearch.yml". I have following questions about the file:-

- Is it mandatory to name the file as elastic-search?
- There is a property named cluster.name in the file, what is the use? If we don't mention any name, will it use any default name?
- I am confused because i removed the name from the YML file but the program still worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Elasticsearch.yml` is a `configuration file`. it contains various configurations related to cluster, node.
- `cluster.name` is the property to set the name of your cluster. Default name of your cluster is `elasticsearch`. You can change it to any name you want.
- If you remove `cluster.name` , it won't affect your program. Default name would be taken.

Answer (score 0):

You can find answers in-line here:

> Is it mandatory to name the file as elastic-search?

Yes, it is mandatory to not rename `elasticsearch.yml`. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16306).

> There is a property named `cluster.name` in the file, what is the use? If we don't mention any name, will it use any default name?

`cluster.name` is used to name your elasticsearch cluster. It has default value `elasticsearch` . But it is highly recommended to change this parameter as this is used to discover and auto-join other nodes. You can read more about this parameter [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html#cluster-name).

> I am confused because i removed the name from the YML file but the program still worked.

Here there is little confusion that you changed `cluster.name` parameter value or completely removed that parameter from `elasticsearch.yml` . If you completely removed that then it still holds default value i.e `elasticsearch` or if you changed it's value then it depends on your program that how it identifying elasticsearch cluster.